# iPhone UIWebView weird build problem

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

This is strange.  I have a custom Nib with a webView, all outlets are set properly.  On the first "Build and Run", whenever I invoke the nib, it's just a blank white screen with my iPhone status bar at the top.  Then, if I click Stop, and Build and Go again (without making any code changes) and I invoke the nib, I get my Nib from Interface Builder exactly the way it should be, operating just fine.

This lasts and works until I make any changes in the custom view controller.  If I make a change and want to test, I have to Build and Go, Stop, and Build and Go again to get my nib to display properly.

Has anyone ever experienced this?  My ViewController is displayed modally.

Keep in mind that I don't make any code changes at all between Build and Go attempts.

Comment: Weird. Are you doing view initialisation code in loadView or init? Have you tried a clean?

Comment: I do have something in -(void)viewDidLoad that creates the NSURLRequest, and then the [statsWebView loadRequest:request] That's the only initialization code I have. Thanks for following up, and no I haven't tried a clean.  I'll give it a shot

Comment: Doing a clean all targets actually made it work the first time, but making a change inside the ViewController had the same result as before.  I'm afraid of submitting to apple (because I can't test the app store release on a device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is that there are 2 nibs with the same name in the bundle.  I am not sure how this happened, but I decided to check my connections (again) and when I opened the nib, it was empty.  "That's odd." I thought to myself.  I went to double click it again and wondered why it was at the bottom of my "Classes folder."  Lo and behold, I had an extra one inside my project, as well as the original in the resources.

Just an FYI!  I guess you can have two of the same file in the bundle...